# Printing viewport

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, 3d, viewport

C# wpf 3D visual studio 2010 net 4.5

Hi

I am trying to print out the 3D image I have created but can not get it right.
The image that is printed is changing in size depending on how large the window is etc.
or it is clipped etc.

What I would like is to print the view port on the printer, 
stretching it so wide as the paper is and keeping aspect ration.

```
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        { return; }

        StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel();
        myPanel.Margin = new Thickness(40);

        Image myImage = new Image();
        myImage.Width = dialog.PrintableAreaWidth - (2 * MYDPI);
        myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, (int)dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(myViewPort);

        myImage.Source = bmp;

        myPanel.Children.Add(myImage);

        myPanel.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
        myPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), myPanel.DesiredSize));

        dialog.PrintVisual(myPanel, myName);
```

Comment: If you know the area to print, why don't you just take a screenshot of that zone and print that instead?

Comment: That is what happend in 

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, (int)dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32); 
        bmp.Render(myViewPort);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked, now the picture get scaled to the size of the paper regardless of
the size of the viewport

...

```
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        { 
            return; 
        }


        Grid grid = new Grid();

        grid.Margin = new Thickness(40);

        //do this for each column
        ColumnDefinition coldef;
        coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
        coldef.Width = new GridLength(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);

        //do this for each row
        RowDefinition rowdef;
        rowdef = new RowDefinition();
        rowdef.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);
        //
        rowdef = new RowDefinition();
        rowdef.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);

        TextBlock myTitle = new TextBlock();
        myTitle.FontSize = 24;
        myTitle.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        myTitle.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        myTitle.Text = myName;

        grid.Children.Add(myTitle);
        //put it in column 0, row 0
        Grid.SetColumn(myTitle, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(myTitle, 0);

        Image myImage = new Image();
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.Width, (int)this.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(myViewPort);

        myImage.Source = bmp;
        myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        grid.Children.Add(myImage);
        //put it in column 0, row 1
        Grid.SetColumn(myImage, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(myImage, 1);

        grid.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
        grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), grid.DesiredSize));

        dialog.PrintVisual(grid, myName);
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but it helped me get printing (with scaling) working properly in a WPF app. The only two notes I'd make for anyone coming to this page in the future is to (1) use `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`, as they handle maximized windows properly, and (2) add the grid margin (x2) to the RenderTargetBitmap width/height, as part of my image was getting cut off until I did so